# Write Pattern in android

Tags: android, pattern-matching

I want to check password when I register in android. It should have some letters (A-Z), some numbers (0-9) and some special characters (-_!@#$%^&*()+=?.,). But it's not working. please help me!

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern               
                .compile("/^[A-Za-z0-9_.@]+$/u");
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `/` and `/u` may not belong to java(I haven't seen them from [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)). What I mean is to change your regex string to be like this:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_.@]+$
```

I test this on my PC, and it works fine. Hope it helps you:)

Answer (score 0):

Use this as pattern. I hope it will help you.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern               
            .compile("([-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+(\.[-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+)*|"([]!#-[^-~ \t]|(\\[\t -~]))+")@[0-9A-Za-z]([0-9A-Za-z-]{0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?(\.[0-9A-Za-z]([0-9A-Za-z-]{0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?)+");
```

Resource Link:
[Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

You can see more and best explanation here

http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/

Short answer:

```
PASSWORD_PATTERN = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})"
```